# Is there a variable that refers to the package base directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a variable (or how to make such a variable) that refers to the package base directory (where `package.json` is)?

The use case:

I am using Babel to compile code from ES6 to ES5. `./src/` to `./dist/`. Then I refer to the `./dist/` code in the [`main` property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) of the `package.json`

The problem happens when `./src/` code uses files that are not JS, e.g. `./src/schemas/*.json`. These files do not exist in `./dist/` folder. Therefore, when referring to non-JavaScript files from `./src/` I need to use a path that keeps a reference to `./src/` file.

I can already do this using `./../src/schemas/foo.json` when requesting a file. Though, thats a fragile approach.

Comment: I know I can simply copy all the non-JavaScript files to `./dist/`, but duplication of content does not seem like an appropriate solution.

Comment: What about symlinks?

Comment: Might be a solution. Need to think about possible downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can simply copy all the non-JavaScript files to ./dist/, but
>   duplication of content does not seem like an appropriate solution.

This is the appropriate solution.

Why ?

- Your `src` folder should hold the source code of your project (not including dependencies & build routines)
- Your `dist` folder is supposed to hold a **standalone version** of your app or website that **you'll be able to distribute "as is"** (you should be able to upload the content of `dist` via ssh/ftp or whatever to your remote server and it should be working)

Note: This thread is more about code organization than code itself (so anybody can have his opinion), but this is the kind of workflow yeoman and lots of build systems use.